# Java Spring @Autowired not working as expected

Tags: java, spring, autowired

My application is not running as expected due to @Autowired. 
Would it because of the codes below?

```
@PropertySource("WEB-INF/config.properties")
public class DBQuery {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
```

I had tried with lots of available solutions and examples for 2 days yet no hope in getting my application running properly. Would greatly appreciate those who can correct me with my codes.

**Error Messages**

```
2016-12-15 14:23:04 WARN  XmlWebApplicationContext:487 - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dbQuery' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/test-servlet.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [java.lang.String]: : No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

**Updated Full Stack Error Messages after tried the solution below**

```
<bean id="dbQuery" class="com.cdmDP.db.DBQuery" >
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="1"/>
</bean>

2016-12-15 15:46:49 ERROR ContextLoader:331 - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'DBQuery' defined in file [D:\program_files\apache-tomcat-8.0.39\webapps\test\WEB-INF\classes\com\test\db\DBQuery.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [java.lang.String]: : No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1139)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4853)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:940)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1816)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
        ... 28 more
```

**com/test/ViewAllData.java**

```
@Controller
public class ViewAllData {
    DBQuery dbQuery;

    @Autowired
    public ViewAllData(DBQuery dbQuery){
        this.dbQuery = dbQuery;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/viewAllData")
    public ModelAndView viewData() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
        String dataTable;
        ResultSet rs = dbQuery.getAllData();
        //processing

        return new ModelAndView("viewAllData", "message", dataTable);
    }
}
```

**com/test/db/DBQuery.java**

```
@Controller
@Service
@PropertySource("WEB-INF/config.properties")
public class DBQuery {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
    String dbUsername = env.getProperty("db.username");
    String dbPassword = env.getProperty("db.password");
    String dbUrl = env.getProperty("db.url");

    String start;
    @Autowired
    public DBQuery(String start) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
        this.start = start;
    }

    public ResultSet getAllDataPassport() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");  
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, dbUsername, dbPassword);

        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        String sql = "select * from testing_table";
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);

        return rs;
    }

}
```

**test-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.test, com.test.db" />
   <context:annotation-config />

    <bean id="viewAllData" class="com.test.ViewAllData"/>
    <bean id="dbQuery" class="com.test.db.DBQuery" >
        <property name="start" value="1"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource" id="messageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="messages" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: What is `Environment`? Where is it defined?

Comment: I highly doubt that there is a bean of type `String` in your context. Your `DBQuery` has a constructor that takes a `String` that constructor is annotated with `@Autowired` hence it requires a bean of that type. However your code is flawed, you shouldn't be using `Connection`s like that (eventually you will run into resource issues). However your application is running exactly like it should as your configuration is wrong.

Comment: @MarounMaroun The Environment is from import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

Comment: @M.Deinum , Sorry.. I don't quite understand your explanation. This is my first time setting up a Spring Java Application from scratch. Currently I'm just testing with the application that will get data from the DB. I just want it to work for now.

Comment: Remove the `@Autowired` annotation from the constructor of class `DBQuery`.

Comment: I provided a (quite long) answer. The first part is about solving your actual question. The remained is about improving your whole structure. (It became more or less a tutorial like answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is flawed in multiple ways.

1. your configuration is flawed due to not understanding annotations and mixing it with XML
2. You should be using a `DataSource` to work with `Connection` objects and properly release them after use
3. You shouldn't have SQL processing code in your controller
4. You shouldn't be constructed HTML in your controller

You have defined your `DBQuery` class with a constructor that takes an argument, you have annotated this constructor with `@Autowired`. Which means Spring will try to create an instance of `DBQuery` (due to your `<context:component-scan />` ) and try to find a bean of the type `String` in your context. That bean isn't there thus it fails.

Also you end up with multiple instances of `DBQuery` due to component scanning and the fact you have one in XML. Remove the XML configuration. Also a component is either a `@Service` or a `@Controller` but not both. And `@PropertySource` on a non `@Configuration` class doesn't do anything.

That being said, and assuming you largely want to use annotations first remove your `@Autowired` constructor and simply create a `setStart` method. It is also more of a `@Repository` then anything else.

```
@Repository
public class DBQuery {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
    String dbUsername = env.getProperty("db.username");
    String dbPassword = env.getProperty("db.password");
    String dbUrl = env.getProperty("db.url");
    String start; 

    public ResultSet getAllDataPassport() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");  
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, dbUsername, dbPassword);

        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        String sql = "select * from testing_table";
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);

        return rs;
    }
}
```

And of course remove the `DBQuery` bean from your XML as well as the bean for `ViewAllData` bean. Those are detected and created by `<context:component-scan />`

Now instead of using the `DriverManager` directly you really should be using a `DataSource` in your code and inject that into your class.

Add the following to your XML configuration.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="WEB-INF/config.properties" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="${db.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
</bean>
```

**Note:** Although the `DriverManagerDataSource` is a `DataSource` don't use it in production. Use a proper connection pool like [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) in that case. The beauty here is that you can just configure that and leave your `DBQuery` as is.

Now instead of injecting the `Environment` and all the properties simply inject a `DataSource` into your `DBQuery` object.

```
@Repository
public class DBQuery {

    private final DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired    
    public DBQuery(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource=dataSource;
    }

    public ResultSet getAllDataPassport() throws SQLException {

        Connection conn = this.dataSource.getConnection();
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        String sql = "select * from testing_table";
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
        return rs;
    }
}
```

However this code is still flawed as you are not closing the `Connection` and `ResultSet` (unless you do that in your controller which would make it even more flawed). Your `getAllDataPassport` should probably be returning a `List` of `Passport` objects (or `DataPassport`). So you would need to move part of the processing/conversion of the controller to your `DBQuery`.

To make working with JDBC easier Spring has the [`JdbcTemplate`] you probably want to write your code using that instead of the `DataSource` as that will manage the resource closing and exception handling for you. You can quite easily use a `RowMapper` to convert each row into a `Passport` object.

In your xml add the following

```
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

And inject that into your `DBQuery` instead of the `DataSource`.

```
@Repository
public class DBQuery {

    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired    
    public DBQuery(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    public List<Passport> getAllDataPassport() {

        String sql = "select * from testing_table";
        return this.jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new PassportRowMapper());
    }
}
```

The code above will execute your query, obtain and close the resources and convert the rows into `Passport` object. You of course need to write the `PassportRowMapper` to convert each row into a `Passport`.

```
public class PassportRowMapper implements RowMapper<Passport> {

    public Passport mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        Passport p = new Passport();
        p.setNumber(rs.getString(1));
        // further logic to get row information
        return p;
    }
}
```

**Note:** Don't do `rs.next` in the `RowMapper` the `JdbcTemplate` takes care of that. You only need to convert a single row into a `Passport`.

Now your controller is freed of the burden to do conversion and not tied to SQL anymore. For testing you could now easily mock the `DBQuery` and unit test your `ViewAllData` controller.

```
@Controller
public class ViewAllData {

    private final DBQuery dbQuery;

    @Autowired
    public ViewAllData(DBQuery dbQuery){
        this.dbQuery = dbQuery;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/viewAllData")
    public ModelAndView viewData() {
        String dataTable;
        List<Passport> passports = dbQuery.getAllDataPassports();
        // List to whatever it needs to be
        return new ModelAndView("viewAllData", "message", dataTable);
    }
}
```

It also looks like in your controller you are converting the `List<Passport` into a `String` which I fear contains a HTML table. You shouldn't be doing tings like that, you should have that logic in the view where it belongs.

In your controller add the list of items to the model.

```
    @RequestMapping("/viewAllData")
    public ModelAndView viewData() {
        String dataTable;
        List<Passport> passports = dbQuery.getAllDataPassports();
        // List to whatever it needs to be
        return new ModelAndView("viewAllData", "passports", passports);
    }
```

Now in your view you can use JSTL to iterate over the collection and create the HTML table.

```
<table>
    <c:forEach items="${passports}" var="passport">
        <tr><td>${passport.number}</td><!-- other columns --></tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Now you have decoupled your View, Model and Controller. You could now even use the same controller to export to PDF, Excel or JSON. Without changing it.

Final tip use the `InternalResourceViewResolver` instead of the plain `UrlBasedViewResolver`. Has a bit more functionality and auto detection of JSTL saves you some configuration.

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view. InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Your explanation is very helpful but I have the error in test-servlet.xml. 
cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'context:placeholder-configurer'.

I have added below yet error.
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"

http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd

Comment: Now everything work like a charm! Thanks for your helpful answer. However, do you mind to paste the link of the good tutorial/ example for the View where I can populate my data to the View instead of constructing the HTML table in my Controller?

Comment: You are using JSP so anything will do... Google is your friend in this case.

Comment: Updated the question with a small section on JSP and model.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in test-servlet.xml dbQuery bean, Use constructor based dependency instead "

```
<bean id="dbQuery" class="com.test.db.DBQuery" >
    <property name="start" value="1"/>
</bean>
```

You need to change it to :

```
<bean id="dbQuery" class="com.test.db.DBQuery" >
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="1"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: This seems right answer because user is doing constructor injection and in xml file it is setter injection.

Comment: Hi, I'm still getting the error for trying this answer.
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}

Comment: @PrakashHariSharma I have edited and updated the latest Full Error Message in the Question as it is too long to post here.

Comment: Try with <constructor-arg value="1"/>